# Weird printf behavior

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am writing a socket program which simulates a simple game like passing the pillow. There is a master program which connects to multiple player programs (which are all connected in a ring network). The master selects a random player and gives it the number of hops the pillow can take. The player then reduces the hops, puts its name on the pillow and passes it to a random neighboring player. Finally when the hop count reaches zero the player returns the pillow to the master who prints the path of the pillow.

For example, in a game of 5 players:
Lets say Player 3 receives the pillow containing "3" (which is the number of hops). 
It passes it on to player 2 (randomly) who receives "2$3" (2 hops, player 3 in trace).
Player 2 passes it back to player 3 who receives "1$3,2" (1 hop, players 3->2).
Player 3 now puts its own name and sends it back to the master who receives "0$3,2,3". The master prints this.

I face a problem in creating a pillow. For small numbers, the program is working perfectly (<750 hops). If I increase it beyond 750 hops then the program randomly stops at ~750 hops and directly jumps to 0. The below is the code which creates the potato in each iteration of the player. It gets an input like "4$6,5,6,7,8,9,8", changes the hops and adds the id at the end. For hops=3, id=7, the output will be "3$6,5,6,7,8,9,8,7".

```
void createPotato(int id, int hops, char pot[20000])
{
    int i, j;
    char t[20000];
    char d[10];

    strcpy(t, pot);
    for(j = 0; t[j] && t[j] != '$'; j++);

    snprintf(pot, 20000, "%d", hops);
    for(i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        if(pot[i] == '\0')
            break;
    pot[i++] = '$';

    if(t[j])
    {
        for(j = j + 1; t[j]; j++)
            pot[i++] = t[j];
        pot[i++] = ',';
    }

    snprintf(d, 10, "%d", id);
    for(j = 0; d[j]; j++)
        pot[i++] = d[j];

    pot[i] = '\0';
}

int getHopsFromPotato(char pot[20000])
{
    char t[20000];
    strcpy(t, pot);
    char *hops = strtok(t, "$");
    return atoi(hops);
}
```

The funny thing is: if I modify the above code to change the part where "id" is being added to the "pot" to the following, it works.

```
snprintf(d, 10, "%d", id);
for(j = 0; d[j]; j++)
    pot[i++] = d[j];
```

to

```
pot[i++] = '0';
```

Then it works. If I change it to

```
pot[i++] = '2';
```

Then it works too. However, when I change it to

```
pot[i++] = '1';
```

Then the execution stops after ~750 hops. I cannot even begin to solve this issue. Not sure if I have given enough details or what I am even supposed to give. The outputs are as follows if helpful.

For players=2, hops= 1000 (where pot[i++] = '0')

```
Pot: 268$1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
Hops: 268

Pot: 266$1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,1
Hops: 266
Pot: 0$1
```

After 266, it suddenly skips all hops after it, erases the Pot and then returns it to the master.

Please let me know if I need to add any details. I did not add the entire code as it is too long.

Comment: Why use `for(i = 0; i < 20000; i++)  if(pot[i] == '\0') break;` instead of `i = strnlen(pot,20000);`?

Comment: Given that the hop count, before the $ character, is set by the 'hops' parameter, the only reason it could get set to 0, like this, is if the 'hops' parameter was set to 0 when invoking your function. In other words, the problem is somewhere else. There is no problem with the shown code (well, there are plenty problems, like potential buffer overflows, etc..., but not that have to do with the issue at hand).

Comment: The functions you have posted look OK. Perhaps you cause a buffer overflow with the `pot[i++]` lines. You will need to show the code that calls these functions. Without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to debug.

Comment: @MichaelBurr `strnlen` is not in ISO C

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know the coding style is quite horrible. It is something I usually take care of but I needed to write this code as fast as possible. Pardon my bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing the potato over a socket, it is likely that as it gets larger, you eventually hit the limit of how much your operating system will send in a single `send`/`recv` call. Make sure that your socket processing code checks the return value to see how much data was actually received and calls `recv` again if necessary.

The issue is likely nondeterministic and not actually related to the actual value you store in the array. The change you have described will result in the same machine code being generated which runs in the same amount of time. The network however is always nondeterministic.

Comment: As you mentioned, the size of the message was becoming too huge for the OS to send over a socket easily. I changed the code to ensure that the players keep sending the pillow to the master after a certain length was reached (100) and let the master parse the entire trace. This worked like a charm!! Thank you!